# What is OWASP ? why we need that?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, owasp

I read some documents they said OWASP is used for security purpose for web application. But Am not clear about that. can any one tell me the purpose, what is the difference normal app(without owasp) & secure app(with owasp) and why we need that. can you give me some runable angularjs example for following things

1)A2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)

2)A3: Broken Authentication and Session Management

3)A4: Insecure Direct Object References

4)A5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)

5)A6: Security Misconfiguration

6)A7: Insecure Cryptographic Storage

7)A9: Insufficient Transport Layer Protection

Answer (score 1):

To simply put it, OWASP is a community highlighting security threats to web application. Hence, it provides information on what are the top security threats (OWASP Top Ten) and a whole bunch of guidelines and best practices when developing web applications that would keep it secure. So the **difference** is whether the developer followed the said guidelines and best practices.

To give an example: **Cross Site Scripting** is when a user tries to execute javascripts in web apps input fields, allowing rogue client-side script to be executed into web pages viewed by other users. XSS exploits the fact that some developers do not validate what the user inputs and merely processes them clientside.

You'll need to research a bit for the rest you have posted. Google is your answer there. :)